# neo4j starting issues (through SSH-Ansible)

Tags: database, ssh, neo4j, vagrant, ansible

I'm having issues with starting Neo4j on my VM. Stoping works fine.
I use Ansible which connects to my VM through SSH and then launches shell commands on it.
Basically, I execute through SSH (Ansible):

```
sudo service neo4j-service start

[...] Neo4j Server...process [13203]... waiting for server to be ready....... OK.\nhttp://localhost:7474/ is ready."
```

But then when I check for process id number 13203 on my VM, I see nothing.
And, when I try stopping the process, it therefore "logically" fails:

```
sudo service neo4j-service stop
ERROR: Neo4j Server not running
```

In other words, either the server says it starts when it doesn't, or the neo4j process is insta killed for some reasons (after end of ssh connetion, or ??).

But when I personaly connect to my virtual machine through a shell and use:

```
sudo service neo4j-service start
```

The process remains started just fine and I can stop it...
Anybody could give me a hint ?

Comment: did you find the answer? I encountered this problem, too. I checked the log and it said that "Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request". still don't know why the request stop the server

Answer (score 3):

why are you running a command to do it? You can use the built-in `service` module, which should pay attention to failures more accurately.

```
- name: start neo4j
  service: name=neo4j status=started enabled=yes
```

Comment: This is the simplest answer and it simply works. See tmtxt comment to know why my command failed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Ansible request pseudo-tty to execute sudo command. To fix this, instead of calling the command directly using the module command, use `nohup` execute that command with output to a non-tty

```
- name: start neo4j
  command: nohup sudo service neo4j-service stop
```

or calling the neo4j script directly

```
- name: start neo4j
  command: nohup /path/to/neo4j/bin/neo4j start
```